# Чем отличается токен discord?

Tags: discord, token

Есть токен бота и есть токен акаунта так вчем разница?
Почему я не могу взять свой токен от дискорда и сделать на основе этого бота?
П. С. Да я пытался взять свой токен но нечего неполучилось

Comment: Читайте документацию...

Comment: либо я в глаза долблюсь и не вижу , либо я не умею читать (можно ссылку для таких как я)

Comment: наверное потому, что бот это отдельная сущность??? это равносильно, что взять ваши паспортные данные и приписать их боту, включая снилс, инн и подобное

Comment: и в чем проблема сгенерировать токен??

Comment: Discord запрещает автоматизацию обычной учетной записи, за это можно получить бан. Поэтому у вас у не работает бот-фреймворк на токене от обычной учетной записи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Пользователь** - это один аккаунт, а **бот** - точно такой же аккаунт, как и пользователь, просто автоматизированный.


В библиотеке `discord.py` есть способ работы с автоматизацией пользователя (вот [ссылка](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.self_bot) на документацию), но у самого Дискорда есть ограничения в этом плане: допустим, ты не сможешь получить объект другого пользователя с помощью своего токена.


И как уже сказали комментаторы выше, за использование селф-ботов, т.е. "пользователей-ботов", можно получить перманентный бан аккаунта от Дискорда, в случае если кто-то на Вас пожалуется.


Поэтому лучше просто заняться разработкой бота, а не селф-бота, и не искать себе приключений. Удачи!